# pandas how get row index by data frame column value

Tags: loops, pandas, indexing

There is my data frame. 
I have "Operation" column, that values in these columns defines loops. For instance Operation  = 4 defines begining of loop with duration 1 and Operation  = 9 is the end of this loop. And so on for A2 and A3 loops. How can i insert values and add new columns if needed A1, A2, A3 and so on with more and more loops defined by start and end operations. Just to emphasize, that in case of overlap would like to create new column or add into existing next column if already exists. Thank you for help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [136]: df
Out[136]:
   a  b  c  operation
0  8  7  5          1
1  3  1  0          2
2  5  4  0          3
3  9  7  7          4
4  4  6  8          5
5  7  8  0          6
6  1  8  8          7
7  0  9  0          8
8  9  9  7          9
9  0  7  3         10

In [137]: df['A1'] = ''

In [138]: df.ix[(df.index >= df[df.operation == 4].index.tolist()) & \
   .....:       (df.index <= df[df.operation == 9].index.tolist()), 'A1'] = 1

In [139]:

In [139]:

In [139]: df['A2'] = ''

In [140]: df.ix[(df.index >= df[df.operation == 2].index.tolist()) & \
   .....:       (df.index <= df[df.operation == 7].index.tolist()), 'A2'] = 2

In [141]: df
Out[141]:
   a  b  c  operation A1 A2
0  8  7  5          1
1  3  1  0          2     2
2  5  4  0          3     2
3  9  7  7          4  1  2
4  4  6  8          5  1  2
5  7  8  0          6  1  2
6  1  8  8          7  1  2
7  0  9  0          8  1
8  9  9  7          9  1
9  0  7  3         10
```

**OLD answer:**

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
   a  b  c OPERATION
0  1  1  0       op2
1  1  5  6       op2
2  7  7  2     START
3  1  6  2       op2
4  7  7  4       op2
5  3  2  0       op2
6  6  9  9       op1
7  6  1  4       END
8  5  3  6       op1
9  9  2  9       op3

In [94]: df[(df.index >= df[df.OPERATION == 'START'].index.tolist()) & \
   ....:    (df.index <= df[df.OPERATION == 'END'].index.tolist())]
Out[94]:
   a  b  c OPERATION
2  7  7  2     START
3  1  6  2       op2
4  7  7  4       op2
5  3  2  0       op2
6  6  9  9       op1
7  6  1  4       END
```

Explanation:

```
In [53]: df.OPERATION == 'START'
Out[53]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: OPERATION, dtype: bool

In [54]: df[df.OPERATION == 'START'].index.tolist()
Out[54]: [2]

In [55]: df.index >= df[df.OPERATION == 'START'].index.tolist()
Out[55]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you much. So if i would like to add into new column 'A' value x between START and END, how can i do that? Thank you

Comment: @Felix, i don't understand what value do you want to put into new column. and what about _other_ rows? Or do you want to have another copy of your DF with rows between START and END?  Could you please update your question with a sample input data set (5-7 rows in text/CSV/dict/JSO/pickle form) and post desired output?

Comment: Thank you a lot, Max. I did example even more complicated. I would like only to create A2 and A3 just in case i have overlap in A1. for instance A3 loop that starts Operation 12 and finished Operation 14 with duration of 8 i preffer to put into A1. New example posted above